# Is it possible to specify rule processing order in Amazon Route 53?

Tags: amazon-route53

I'd like to setup a catch-all for my subdomains:

```
*.domain.com.    CNAME    domain.com
```

But, a few specific subdomains should have their own entry:

```
mail.domain.com.    A        X.X.X.X
*.domain.com.       CNAME    domain.com
```

The problem is, **how can I specify that I want the first rule to be processed before the catch-all?**

As far as I can see, there is no way to reorder the rules. So, if I create a rule *after* the catch-all, the catch-all might be processed before the specific rule.

There's a *weight* parameter, but it doesn't look like it's designed for this purpose, but for load balancing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reply from the AWS support (emphasize mine):

> If you setup a wildcard DNS entry for your Domain this will catch all
>   queries where you haven`t specified a record.
>
> As example:
>
> ```
> localhost.domain.com. A 127.0.0.1
> *.domain.com.         A 127.0.0.2
> www.test.domain.com.  A 127.0.0.3
> ```
>
> A query for localhost.domain.com. will return the specified A Record 127.0.0.1
>   A query for test.domain.com. will return the wildcard record 127.0.0.2
>   A query for www.test.domain.com. will return the specified record 127.0.0.3
>
> This means **a specified Record within your hosted Zone will always have
>   a higher priority as a wildcard record**.